# Clustering points on a line

Tags: dynamic-programming

> Given pixel values $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n \in \{0,\ldots,255\}$ and $k$, find
> $$
> \min_{v_1,\ldots,v_k} \sum_{i=1}^n \min_{1 \leq j \leq k} (r_i - v_j)^2.
> $$

**My attempt:** Let $F[L,c]$ be the minimum cost, where $L$ is the last color that was chosen, and $c$ is the remaining colors. Since the order of pixels don't matter, let's store the frequency of pixel values in an array $A$. Let $\mathrm{costRange}(L,i)$:

$$
\mathrm{costRange}(L,i) = \sum_{i=L+1}^i A[i] (i-L)^2
$$

$$
F(L,c) = \min_{L<i \leq 255} (F(i,c-1) + \mathrm{costRange}(L,i))
$$

I'm stuck at the base case.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Please argue how *dynamic programming* suggested itself here. Ideas: start with "the 256-bin histogram", divide into $k$ parts with same number of non-empty bins, [clustering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), [image quantisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(image_processing)).

Comment: The formula for costRange seems to contain an error (upper range of summation over $i$).

Comment: I don't understand your definition of what $F$ is supposed to represent, and you don't specify what costRange is supposed to represent.

Comment: Usually the base case is easy to compute, and this is probably the case here as well. If you understand what $F$ is computing, then you should be able to understand what the base cases are and what their values are.

Comment: It seems that you are implicitly allowing the cluster centers to be only $0,\ldots,255$.

Comment: My definition of the matrix is flawed.

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this task or the motivation?  Please credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: I encourage you to see https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info and follow the systematic approach outlined there, then [edit] your question to show your progress and at what specific stage you got stuck.